# web3.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: next.js, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am testing out my subscription method on the test network Sepolia. I tried using this paySubscription function on hardhat and it worked, but i need it on frontend in next.js and now it prompts me with metamask and when i submit the transaction i get Transaction reverted by evm error after about 15 seconds.

Here is the function i am trying to pay to, followed by my frontend function.

````
    function paySubscription(uint256 _period) external payable virtual { 
        if(msg.value != ethFee * _period) revert FailedEthTransfer();
        if(paymentExpire[msg.sender] == 0) {
           paymentExpire[msg.sender] = (block.timestamp) + (_period * 30 days); 
        } else {
            paymentExpire[msg.sender] += _period * 30 days;
        }
        
    }```
````

```
async function paySubscription() {
// Check if MetaMask is installed
 if (
 typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined" ||
 typeof window.web3 !== "undefined"
) {
const provider = window["ethereum"] || window.web3.currentProvider;
const w3 = new Web3(provider);

// Request account access
const accounts = await ethereum.request({
  method: "eth_requestAccounts",
});

const contract = new w3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

const gasLimit = 200000;
let gasPrice = await w3.eth.getGasPrice(); // Get current gas price
let gasPriceGwei = w3.utils.fromWei(gasPrice, "gwei");
let increasedGasPrice = (parseFloat(gasPriceGwei) * 2).toString();
let gasPriceWei = w3.utils.toWei(increasedGasPrice, "gwei");
const valueToSend = w3.utils.toWei("1", "ether"); 

const receipt = await contract.methods.paySubscription(1).send({
  from: accounts[0],
  value: valueToSend,
  gas: gasLimit,
  gasPrice: gasPriceWei,
});

return receipt;
} else {

}
}.
```